# Find the cause of intermittent "Incorrect Password" errors when using curl to connect to third party using encrypted private key

Tags: php, ssl, curl, openssl

We have a PHP web application that is used to periodically send data to a third party API. Communication is naturally done over SSL and a password protected key is held locally on our server and fed into curl. Here is the curl set up code:

```php
/**
     * @return Http
     */
    public function post($url, $content, array $headers = array(), $ssl = true) {
        $h = curl_init($this->getUrl($url));
        $opts = array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $content,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
        );

        if ($ssl) {
            $opts[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST] = 2;
            $opts[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = true;
        }

        if ($this->certFile && $ssl) {
            $opts[CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE] = $this->certType;
            $opts[CURLOPT_SSLCERT] = $this->certFile;
            if ($this->certKey) { 
                $opts[CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD] = $this->certKey;
            }
            if ($this->sslKeyFile) {
                $opts[CURLOPT_SSLKEY] = $this->sslKeyFile;
            }
            else if ($this->certCA) {
                $opts[CURLOPT_CAINFO] = $this->certCA;
            }
        }

        curl_setopt_array($h, $opts);
        $this->handle = $h;
        return $this;
    }
```

The web application might attempt to make 10 separate synchronous requests using the above code. We are seeing intermittent problems where curl vebose logging returns the following error (hostnames and IPs masked for security):

```
* About to connect() to *** port 443 (#59)
*   Trying xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx...
* Connected to *** (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) port 443 (#59)
*   CAfile: /path/to/ca.pem
  CApath: none
* Unable to load client key: Incorrect password
* NSS error -8177 (SEC_ERROR_BAD_PASSWORD)
* The security password entered is incorrect.
* Closing connection 59
```

When we manage to make a successful connection, an extra line is included in the log output:

```
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
```

This line is missing in all failed connections and seems like it might hold a clue. That path is available and accessible on the servers handling the requests.

The password that is being supplied to curl is correct and does open the key without an issues on the command line.

Our servers are running CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core) with PHP 7.0.33 and CURL version 7.29.0 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.29.0 NSS/3.36 zlib/1.2.7 libidn/1.28 libssh2/1.4.3

Has anyone ever seen this before? We originally thought it was a file access issue as our private key is stored on high availability network storage.

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was happening? I'm experiencing pretty much the same thing with php-fastcgi.

The extra weird thing is it is happening for requests with a CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD and with it omitted.

Answer (score 0):

We have exact the same problem.

One particular moment - the problem was on server, running `php-fastcgi`.

We have 12 threads of `fastcgi`.
2 of them started later then other 10.

And this two thread always have  `SEC_ERROR_BAD_PASSWORD` - on every request.

The other 10 threads were always good.

In case you are using fastcgi too, you can log threads pid by adding:

```
$pid = getmypid();
```

to your script and find out which thread are broken.

In our case, after killing those two broken threads, every request was alright.

Have no idea, why those two threads were broken - maybe they started at the moment when something was misconfigured.